# malicious link: Which kind of attack has this website suffered?

Tags: security, spam, virus

I have received a spam email (not detected by the filter) and contained the following link (Please DO NOT CLICK if you are not confident in being virus protected):

`http://www.artinhands.com/wp-content/plugins/telekom/telekom_deutschland_gmbh`

Using linux, I had no consequences in clicking over there, it makes you download a zip file containing an exe file. Apparently that website has been victim of an attack, in which term should I report it to the owner of the website?

I must say, the email we received was really well forged, it is the "best" virus mail I have seen in a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the owner isn't present or doesn't care, but the usual way to do this is to either report the spam to the server hosting provider (usually found by doing a simple whois).

As far as how it happened there's too many ways to count.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ whois artinhands.com | grep @
Registrar Abuse Contact Email: domainabuse@tucows.com
Reseller: support@yola.com
Registrant Email: artinhands@hotmail.com
Admin Email: artinhands@hotmail.com
Tech Email: artinhands@hotmail.com
    Yola, Inc, support@yola.com
```

Looks like artinhands@hotmail.com is a sensible place to report it.